# Source of this drasha?

Tags: sources-mekorot, creation, drush

I want to give over a drasha I heard, but I cannot recall who said it originally. The drasha goes:

> [The Midrash says](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.4.6) that one of the reasons there is no "ki tov" on
>   the second day of Creation is because [machloket](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/587) was created when
>   the upper and lower waters were separated.
>
> To this, the question can be asked about the division between light
>   and darkness on the first day. [There is definitely a "ki tov" then.](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.4)
>
> The answer is that things of the same type (bodies of water) should
>   not be separated, but it *is* appropriate to separate things of
>   different types (light and darkness). Thus it is a tragedy if Jews
>   fight among themselves, but a Jew does not have to seek out the
>   friendship of non-Jews.

I am looking for the name of the Rabbi who said this or the book where it was stated.

Comment: What about Kohanim and Leviyim? Should they not befriend mere Yisraelim? I don't see how this drasha is defining "type".

Comment: @DoubleAA OP was asking for a possible source of this. It is up to you if you like it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do not know where you originally saw this I found references to it by googlin `machlokes second day creation`

[Rabbi Frand on Bereishis](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5759/bereishis.html) goes into this subject.

> On the second day, G-d divided the upper and the lower waters. This
>   was not a case of good water and bad water; of True water and False
>   water. This was a case of making a division between two equally valid
>   components. Regarding such division we do not say, "It was good". This
>   was an unfortunate division. A division was necessary, but there is no
>   'ki tov' on that day because conceptually there is no reason to have
>   machlokes between 'water' and 'water'.
>
> But the first day was different. On the first day, the division was
>   between Light and Dark (Or v'Choshech). By analogy, this represents
>   separation between Truth and Falsehood, between the forces of Good and
>   the forces of Evil. There we must divide. We must delineate. We must
>   say this is Light and this is Dark; This is True and this is False.
>   This is a machlokes, but it is a machlokes that warrants a 'Ki Tov'.
>   It is a necessary machlokes -- a division that must be made.

A reference to Rashi in [Parshas Korach](http://www.torah.org/advanced/jerusalemviews/5759/class13.html#)

> Unlike the other days of creation, the Torah does not conclude its
>   description of the second day with the words 'Ki Tov'. On this day,
>   G-d completes His work without seeing the good. Chazal explain that
>   Gehinnom and Machlokes (dispute) were both created on Yom Sheni, as
>   indicated by the splitting of the heavenly and earthly waters. This
>   day remains unfinished, its Tov not evident until Yom Shlishi.
>
> Each of the daily songs, the Psalms recited at the close of morning
>   prayers, reflect the particular aspect of creation revealed on that
>   day. Hence, on Yom Rishon, we proclaim that 'the world is God's and
>   everything in it'.
>
> On Yom Sheni we repeat the song of the B'nai Korach, the beauty of
>   Jerusalem and the palace of the King.
>
> Who were the B'nai Korach and why do they sing on Yom Sheni?
>
> "And the sons of Korach did not die - They were in the original plan.
>   At the time of the Machlokes, they had thoughts of Tshuva, therefore
>   an elevated place in Gehinnom was established for them, and there they
>   dwelled." (Rashi, Bamidbar, 26,11)

[For Heaven's Sake!](http://www.midreshetmoriah.com/torah/view.asp?id=877)

> The Ohr Gedaliyahu explains that on the first day of Creation, which
>   the Torah calls “the Day of One,” the revelation of Hashem in the
>   physical world was perfectly clear.  Multiplicity and disparity were
>   not yet part of the physical world in a way that would hide Hashem’s
>   Oneness.  On the second day, the concept of diversity and multiplicity
>   became a reality in the world (the firmament separated between the
>   waters).  It is this multiplicity that is the essence of physical
>   reality, which Hashem uses to hide the clear manifestation of His
>   Oneness, thus setting the stage for the operation of human free will. 
>   The second day of Creation represents a mixed bag of sorts: on the one
>   hand, Hashem’s purpose is that His Unity should be hidden by physical
>   reality only to be revealed by the efforts of Jews making free-will
>   choices; on the other hand, the multiplicity actually creates the
>   possibility for the very erroneous perception that Hashem, ch”v, does
>   not exist!  This latter point explains why the verse כי טוב (“It was
>   good”) does not appear on the second day; how could it be remotely
>   good that there could be even a thought that Hashem does not exist,
>   ch”v?

Comment: :-D I found 3 references to this drasha in [Rav Frand](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/)! He quotes Rav Shlomo Breuer.

Comment: @MichaelSandler Yes i saw the reference to Rav Breuer in the one I linked to. However, that was not specifically what you referred to - division between Bnai Yisrael and goyim.